Considering that Exodus 20;5 forbids creating images, bowing down and service to idols must the believers bow to fellow man?
Exodus 20:5 is a command that is in 3 parts that man must not indulge in; not to create an image, not to bow down and not to serve.
Many people groups enjoy the practice of bowing to greater powers as a form of respect and subservience. But what ever explanations we give to bowing down as long as it is to another man it is done great respect. Equals will not bow. Men do bow to their fellow but children, girls, women and subordinates are expected to bow. David and God was bowed to and worship in 1 Chronicles 29:20 a total violation of the demand of God on man! What makes the church fail to be categorical in guiding the followers on the matter of bowing to fellows especially in Africa, China, Japan and India? Isn't this still just gender and status discrimination to still maintain bowing in the name cultural values?

The command in Exodus 20:5 is not to make an image that will be worshipped as a god (or goddess). The command is not to bow down in worship to any such image as to a god (or goddess). The command is not to serve any such image in ways of worship as of a deity (which could include polishing it, laying offerings before it, going to war in the name of it, prostrating oneself before it, carrying it aloft for public adoration etc.)
The key element is that of worship. Whether to an image, an idol, or a human, or an animal, or a lump of stone or metal supposed to have come miraculously to earth - the only true, living God, the maker of heaven and earth, has forbidden us to worship anyone or anything other than Himself.
When people are in a court-room and the judge comes in, it is a mark of respect to stand up and to give a bow (whether of the head, or from the waist). Nobody is worshipping the judge. However, we do see on a massive scale today adoration and worship of individuals or music groups, or sporting 'idols'. The frenetic level of  time, money and adoration spent on those people at their events could well be considered idolatry, despite those idols not being carved out of materials. It is what is in the person's heart that God sees. Not everyone flocking to their events will be so adoring as to have tipped over into worship, but there clearly are some who live (and might even die) for their idol. Witness the packed-full open stadiums where Taylor Swift has appeared this past week. Listen to what excited fans say about her, and the lengths they have gone to just to get a distant glimpse of their idol. Most of her fans are females. None of them are being coerced or even feel any obligation to give such support. It's unlikely any of them would admit to worshipping her, yet the main criteria of worship can sometimes be seen. Do religious leaders point this danger out? Some do.
Yet the text in question does not rule out respectful bowing to other humans when there is no worship involved. The Old Testament has examples of godly people showing such due respect to those higher in authority than themselves, but also of where they drew the line and would not prostrate themselves.
We each have to be clear in our own heart and mind on this vital matter, remembering that "The heart is deceitful above all, and desperately wicked; who can know it?" Jeremiah 17:9. Then the Lord God speaks in the next verse saying, "I the Lord search the heart, I try the reins, even to give every man according to his ways, according to the fruit of his doings." Never mind how religious leaders categorise such matters - how will God judge us? We cannot offload our responsibility onto others.
